# How to create a bar chart in jasper studio?

Tags: jasper-reports, bar-chart, categories, jaspersoft-studio

I am completely new to jasper report. I am trying to create a bar chart with  this data structure but unable to achieve.

```
Name    Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4
abc     60  96  79  85
def     83  77  83  73
ghi     94  69  67  87
```

is it possible to create the chart with the above structure or should I change the data structure to get the bar chart.

This is sample jrxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.3.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.3.0  -->
<!-- 2016-09-12T11:37:15 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="test" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="9153320a-9e2c-4254-80a5-669c62ee70f6">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="mysql-stratupdev"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select * from  stratupdev.test1 ]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="q1" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="q2" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="q3" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="q4" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="111" height="30" uuid="f55a3f0f-fc46-46ff-a76c-6746cae5ac78"/>
                <text><![CDATA[name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="111" y="0" width="111" height="30" uuid="5b0b0684-f63c-495b-b8b2-afd7a51487f6"/>
                <text><![CDATA[q1]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="222" y="0" width="111" height="30" uuid="2db0ef96-cabe-4bc1-b930-31ec7e44ccbc"/>
                <text><![CDATA[q2]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="333" y="0" width="111" height="30" uuid="1ec47906-2e4b-4014-b6d9-a4333c44005a"/>
                <text><![CDATA[q3]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="444" y="0" width="111" height="30" uuid="8e655e66-48dc-4806-93f9-e8514678e5d7"/>
                <text><![CDATA[q4]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="111" height="30" uuid="97e4aa43-c7b7-4335-94b3-a8f4cc04983f"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="111" y="0" width="111" height="30" uuid="032570f4-bc42-4974-b5d9-e1a57d75a9b0"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{q1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="222" y="0" width="111" height="30" uuid="5a5303d6-c343-4b42-ab45-3c42a7784309"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{q2}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="333" y="0" width="111" height="30" uuid="15a97e0a-8e64-4124-b99e-a59bd4fd1975"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{q3}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="444" y="0" width="111" height="30" uuid="a503c376-e3c5-49e2-8891-6ce6e638ae26"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{q4}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="213" splitType="Stretch">
            <barChart>
                <chart evaluationTime="Report">
                    <reportElement x="0" y="13" width="555" height="200" uuid="04fefe3b-b0c7-4aa5-bd45-8d654c81bfa5"/>
                    <chartTitle/>
                    <chartSubtitle/>
                    <chartLegend/>
                </chart>
                <categoryDataset>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA["SERIES 1"]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{q1}]]></valueExpression>
                    </categorySeries>
                </categoryDataset>
                <barPlot>
                    <plot/>
                    <itemLabel/>
                    <categoryAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat/>
                    </categoryAxisFormat>
                    <valueAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat/>
                    </valueAxisFormat>
                </barPlot>
            </barChart>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

But I want the output as shown in this image.

[image]

Comment: Yes, can you show how you would like the bar chart and maybe some jrxml that  you tried.

Comment: I have edited my question by adding the jrxml and desired output of chart.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The chart you like to display have **4 category series** (Q1,Q2,Q3 and Q4), which means you need to add all these category series separately.

```
<categoryDataset>
    <categorySeries>
        <seriesExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></seriesExpression>
        <categoryExpression><![CDATA["Q1"]]></categoryExpression>
        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{q1}]]></valueExpression>
    </categorySeries>
    <categorySeries>
        <seriesExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></seriesExpression>
        <categoryExpression><![CDATA["Q2"]]></categoryExpression>
        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{q2}]]></valueExpression>
    </categorySeries>
    <categorySeries>
        <seriesExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></seriesExpression>
        <categoryExpression><![CDATA["Q3"]]></categoryExpression>
        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{q3}]]></valueExpression>
    </categorySeries>
    <categorySeries>
        <seriesExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></seriesExpression>
        <categoryExpression><![CDATA["Q4"]]></categoryExpression>
        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{q4}]]></valueExpression>
    </categorySeries>
</categoryDataset>
```

As you can see the `categoryExpression` I have set manually to "Q1","Q2".. etc and the `valueExpression` is pointing to the value of each category, while the `seriesExpression` will always be the same the `$F{name}` (it never changes in our categories)

In **JasperSoft Studio**  (double click chart to open Dialog) you do this by adding Series and then select each series to set Value and Category for the selected series

[image: JasperSoft Studio]

**Final result** of your report setting this `categoryDataset`

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me with screenshots.

Comment: @leelavinodh Your welcome, I love to draw free-hand circles : )

Comment: One more addition information required. Along with this output how can I show one of the series as secondary axis.

Comment: @leelavinodh you can start by looking at this question and answer [multi-axis example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35868214/how-to-add-xy-line-to-bar-chart-creating-a-multitype-chart-with-another-axis), it will be hard to explain all in comments, try it out if you have troubles, pass a new question showing where you are stuck