# Jasper Reports - Multi axis chart - Only one plot showing

Tags: java, charts, jasper-reports

I'm trying to create a multi axis chart with one plot which shows a bar chart and another plot which shows a line chart. I found the multi axis chart to do this, but when I run my code only one plot is showing (image provided [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBxQO.png)). Any idea's on how to solve this?

In my search for a solution I came accross [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35868214/how-to-add-xy-line-to-bar-chart-creating-a-multitype-chart-with-another-axis#35872341), but when I execute this it just does the same.

(When I switch the order of the barChart and lineChart in the jrxml it only shows the lineChart. Code provided below.)

**Java bean**

```
public class OperationSuccessrateBean {
    private Integer week;
    private Integer totalOrders;
    private Double successrate;

    public OperationSuccessrateBean(Integer week, Integer totalOrders, Double successrate) {
        this.week = week;
        this.totalOrders = totalOrders;
        this.successrate = successrate;
    }

    public Integer getWeek() {
        return week;
    }

    public Integer getTotalOrders() {
        return totalOrders;
    }

    public Double getSuccessrate() {
        return successrate;
    }
}
```

**Java: Filling the report**

```
private void setOperationSuccessrate(String operationType, Map<String, Object> paramMap,
        List<OperationSuccessrateBean> successrateBeans) {
    paramMap.put(operationType + "_OPERATION_SUCCESSRATE_SET", new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(
            successrateBeans));
    paramMap.put(operationType + "_OPERATION_SUCCESSRATE_ORDERS_SET",
            new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(successrateBeans));
}
```

**jrxml: define datasets and parameters**

```
<subDataset name="loadOperationSuccesrateSet" uuid="247b3e44-ef98-45f4-a909-e8b5678acc8f">
    <field name="week" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="totalOrders" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="successrate" class="java.lang.Double"/>
</subDataset>
<subDataset name="loadOperationSuccesrateOrdersSet" uuid="247b3e44-ef98-45f4-a909-e8b5678acc8f">
    <field name="week" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="totalOrders" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="successrate" class="java.lang.Double"/>
</subDataset>
<parameter name="LOAD_OPERATION_SUCCESSRATE_SET" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource" isForPrompting="false"/>
<parameter name="LOAD_OPERATION_SUCCESSRATE_ORDERS_SET" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource" isForPrompting="false"/>
```

**jrxml: multi chart**

```
<multiAxisChart>
    <chart evaluationTime="Report">
        <reportElement x="0" y="41" width="550" height="200" uuid="5078c050-dd35-43db-bf30-d04152672bd6"/>
        <chartTitle/>
        <chartSubtitle/>
        <chartLegend/>
    </chart>
    <multiAxisPlot>
        <plot/>
        <axis position="rightOrBottom">
            <lineChart>
                <chart evaluationTime="Report">
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="25" width="270" height="175" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="013d7a7d-2280-46d0-8d44-d537d062a182"/>
                    <chartTitle color="#000000"/>
                    <chartSubtitle color="#000000"/>
                    <chartLegend textColor="#000000" backgroundColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                </chart>
                <categoryDataset>
                    <dataset>
                        <datasetRun subDataset="loadOperationSuccesrateSet" uuid="53426928-1245-4443-97da-509b00ba1f98">
                            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{LOAD_OPERATION_SUCCESSRATE_SET}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                        </datasetRun>
                    </dataset>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA["Success rate"]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{week}]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{successrate}]]></valueExpression>
                    </categorySeries>
                </categoryDataset>
                <linePlot>
                    <plot/>
                    <categoryAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat/>
                    </categoryAxisFormat>
                    <valueAxisLabelExpression><![CDATA["Success rate"]]></valueAxisLabelExpression>
                    <valueAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat labelColor="#000000" tickLabelColor="#000000" tickLabelMask="#0%" axisLineColor="#000000">
                            <labelFont/>
                        </axisFormat>
                    </valueAxisFormat>
                    <rangeAxisMinValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></rangeAxisMinValueExpression>
                    <rangeAxisMaxValueExpression><![CDATA[1]]></rangeAxisMaxValueExpression>
                </linePlot>
            </lineChart>
        </axis>
        <axis>
            <barChart>
                <chart evaluationTime="Report">
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="15a15c89-a2d4-4971-b4b3-1c5ac224a91e"/>
                    <chartTitle color="#000000"/>
                    <chartSubtitle color="#000000"/>
                    <chartLegend textColor="#000000" backgroundColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                </chart>
                <categoryDataset>
                    <dataset>
                        <datasetRun subDataset="loadOperationSuccesrateOrdersSet" uuid="4d001c74-1fde-47cd-b525-85d828d6ccf2">
                            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{LOAD_OPERATION_SUCCESSRATE_ORDERS_SET}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                        </datasetRun>
                    </dataset>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA["TotalOrders"]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{week}]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{totalOrders}]]></valueExpression>
                    </categorySeries>
                </categoryDataset>
                <barPlot>
                    <plot/>
                    <itemLabel/>
                    <categoryAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat/>
                    </categoryAxisFormat>
                    <valueAxisLabelExpression><![CDATA["# Orders"]]></valueAxisLabelExpression>
                    <valueAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat labelColor="#000000" tickLabelColor="#000000" tickLabelMask="# ##0" axisLineColor="#000000">
                            <labelFont/>
                        </axisFormat>
                    </valueAxisFormat>
                    <rangeAxisMinValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></rangeAxisMinValueExpression>
                </barPlot>
            </barChart>
        </axis>
    </multiAxisPlot>
</multiAxisChart>
```

When I run my code without the multi axis chart so just to create the 2 plots next to each other it creates just fine. So I assume the data is correctely passed to the report.

The relevant libraries I use are:

- net.sf.jasperreports.engine-6.4.0.jar
- jfreechart-1.0.19.jar

Comment: I just found a workaround for this. When I added a 3rd plot to the multi axis chart this one was also shown. So to solve my problem added a new lineChart and moved this to the first place in the mulitaxis.

New problem was that I had an additional value axis on the right, so I hid one of the axises by setting all color for the value axis to #FFFFF.

I filled a [bug](https://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-library/issues/9861) with jasperreports for this problem

Answer (score 0):

Lorenz, I had the same issue.
The reason for the missing graph was that I was passing directly a net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource as parameter in the report.
Apparently for this to work you have to pass a List:

```
<parameter name="FIRST_DATA_SOURCE" class="java.util.List" isForPrompting="false"/>
<parameter name="SECOND_DATA_SOURCE" class="java.util.List" isForPrompting="false"/>
```

and then create the JRBeanCollectionDataSource inside the report:

```
<dataset>
    <datasetRun subDataset="YOUR_SUBDATASET" uuid="a5941ba5-2088-4a31-8236-64704b54d979">
        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{FIRST_DATA_SOURCE})]]></dataSourceExpression>
    </datasetRun>
</dataset>
```

In the post you referenced it was used this way and it worked!

Comment: You can pass a JRDatasource also, that should not be a problem, I would guess you had a problem with the datasource (maybe you used it twice) and it does not auto rewind. ps I wrote the original post you are referring to

Comment: I know you can pas JRDatasource. This is what I was doing with a Timeseries graph. But when I tried it with a MultiAxis graph containing 2 Timeseries only the second one was displayed. I checked everything and found no issue, I swapped the sources and saw the first data set OK, but now the second was missing. Then after 3 hours of different attempts, I just changed the parameters to be list, Java to send a List<MyBean> and the JRDatasource to be initialized in the template and it worked.

Comment: and you are sure you did not use same JRDatasource anywhere else?, hence you can't re-use a JRDatasource if you do not rewind it. If so that is a strange bug and if I have some time I will try to reproduce it.